# SAS / Graph: Creating editable (ungroupable) graphs in powerpoint 2010

Tags: sas, png, powerpoint, rtf

I have been creating graphs using proc gplot and ods rtf destination for a while. This would create output in word (with graphs embedded as `.png` files). I'm currently using device=png option.

To edit the graphs, titles, footnotes etc I would simply copy and paste each graph into Powerpoint 2010 then ungroup. This enabled me to change most aspects of each graph.

However I have upgraded to SAS 9.4 recently and now when I select "Ungroup" in powerpoint the graph simply disappears and I'm left with a blank slide!

If anyone could help that would be great. I did try ODS powerpoint by the way but that simply added graphs as `.png` and then had the same issue when ungrouping.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you planning to edit?

Comment: The whole graph, labels, title, legend etc. Once ungrouped, most of the graph is editable.

Comment: Perhaps you could put code to reproduce what you're describing here.  I don't use `GPLOT` (I use `SGPLOT`) but all I can get out of `GPLOT` is a single graph, definitely not editable.

Comment: @Joe Not sure if it is an Office 2010 bug or SAS bug.  But I tried with SGPLOT using ODS PowerPoint and ODS RTF and couldn't ungroup it.  e.g. `ods graphics/imagefmt=emf; ods powerpoint file="d:\junk\myppt.pptx"; ods rtf file="d:\junk\myrtf.rtf";proc sgplot data=sashelp.class; scatter x=height y=weight;run;ods rtf close;ods powerpoint close;`  Same question also discussed at https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-GRAPH-and-ODS-Graphics/Creating-editable-ungroupable-graphs-in-powerpoint-2010/m-p/391025

Comment: If you're using SGPLOT might as well use the ODS Graphics Editor ...

Comment: Outputting to RTF and then copying the graph to PPT seems to work for others recently. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Analytics-U/Cannot-output-editable-SGPLOT-graphs-directly-to-Powerpoint/m-p/322576